# How to create a installation program in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a simple program. I want to set the path and some properties for users, so I need to make the software be installed. I can use VC++ to create "exe" file, but I don't know how I can create a installation package.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of setup authoring tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Advanced Installer has a free version which is easy to use for simple installers: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html

Although it has been deprecated, you can also try the Visual Studio setup project: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353